# If and only if a string contains a character not including spaces

Tags: java, string

I think is is a simple problem and I'm just point blank right now.
In Java I want to find out if a string only contains a character but spaces are allowed. 
Below is what I'm trying to accomplish.

`"     }" = True`

`"}" = True`

`"     }    }" = False`

Comment: Character.isWhiteSpace(Char) tests if a character is white space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `trim()` to remove leading and trailing whitespace. Then check the resulting String's length.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this regex : `"\\s*.\\s*"`

```
String regex = "\\s*.\\s*";
System.out.println(" }".matches(regex));   // prints true
System.out.println("}".matches(regex));    // prints true
System.out.println(" } }".matches(regex)); // prints false
```

Comment: regex for a simple problem?